# pandas: calculate the daily average, grouped by label

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I want to create a graph with lines represented by my `label`

so in this example picture, each line represents a distinct label

[image]

The data looks something like this where the x-axis is the datetime and the y-axis is the count.

```
datetime, count, label
1656140642, 12, A
1656140643, 20, B
1656140645, 11, A
1656140676, 1, B
```

Because I have a lot of data, I want to aggregate it by 1 hour or even 1 day chunks.

I'm able to generate the above picture with

```
# df is dataframe here, result from pandas.read_csv
df.set_index("datetime").groupby("label")["count"].plot
```

and I can get a time-range average with

```
df.set_index("datetime").groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='2min')).mean().plot()
```

but I'm unable to get both rules applied. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.pivot` ([documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot.html?highlight=pivot)) function to create a convenient structure where `datetime` is index and the different `labels` are the columns, with `count` as values.

```py
df.set_index('datetime').pivot(columns='label', values='count')
```

output:

```py
label          A    B
datetime        
1656140642  12.0    NaN
1656140643  NaN     20.0
1656140645  11.0    NaN
1656140676  NaN     1.0
```

Now when you have your data in this format, you can perform simple aggregation over the index (with `groupby` / `resample`/ whatever suits you) so it will be applied each column separately. Then plotting the results is just plotting different line for each column.